# Git: Push changes after "git rm"

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I deleted a file using `git rm test` and currently this is the output of `git status .`

```
Noob@Noob:/media/data/bitbucket/pythonscripts$ git status .
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    test
#
```

Now when I try to push the change in my repo using `git push` it says `Everything up-to-date`. I understand that normally one needs to first `add` and than `commit` before push but in my case what do I add beacause I have already deleted the file.

Also if I do `git commit -m "commit message"` will this override all my commits because currently I have no file to attach this commit to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After doing `git rm` you need to do `git commit`. Git says that `Everything up-to-date` is because you have not created a commit with this file removed.

For example if you do `git reset --hard` you'll see that your file is back.

In general `git rm` is no different from `git add`.

---

> will this override all my commits

No it won't, it will create a new commit with this file removed.

Answer (score 4):

There are three steps to answer your question.

```
1. git rm #your_files

2. git commit -m "#your_comments"

3. git push origin #your_local_branch:#your_remote_branch
```